# How maximaze very complex problem in a few hours using some server?

Tags: maximum, cloud-deploy, computational-complexity

I need to execute a code that runs a `maximize` function built-in function with symbolic variables. The problem is that my computer has not enough memory (has 4 GB of RAM) and flops. Have you any idea how can I execute this code in some cloud in reference of your experience? I was thinking about Amazon AWS but I don't know if is a good solution because of my code will execute on single thread (?) and using more thread do not help me or some other stuff that I don't know. How optimise this code or found any solution?

The code is the following:

```
 d=((1-z*(1-x))*p*a-(q+b)*(y*x*z*p*a+r+w))/(2*c*w*(y*x*z*p*a+r+w))
 v=((1-z*(1-x))*p*a*d-(q+b)*w*d-c*w^2*d^2)/r+((1-z*(1-x))(k-d))/(r+w)
 Maximize[{v,0<=z<=1,x>=0,p>0,a>0,a*p<1,q>0,b>0,b+q>=1,0<=w<=r,0<=r<=1,c>0,k>0,(1-z*(1-x))*p*a-(q+b)*(y*x*z*p*a+r+w)>0},x]
```

I need to find a solution with symbolic state (i.e. not a number but a variable)

Comment: Adding any relevant information, even the code and the problem, will cut to the chase.

Comment: We cannot help you without understanding the function, or at least more information about the function.

Comment: I've just added the code

Comment: @alessandro308 would [FindMaximum](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMaximum.html) work for you? It's a numerical optimization so should be much less memory intensive.

Comment: Note that both `q` and `b` should not be used, since only their sum is significant.  Note that `p` and `a` are always multiplied, so only their product is significant.  Can you eliminate `c` by combining it with `k`?   Try to reduce the number of parameters and maybe try something like `Minimize[ Denominator[ Simplify[ v ] ], x]` , if you know the denominator of `v` is non-negative.  Maybe try to set the denominator of `v` equal to zero, if you know `v` is positive.